# Frequent random access of large arrays

Tags: c, memory-management, hash, large-data

I have to implement 4 Hash Tables. The size of hash tables are going to be very large ~ 1 GB Each. The hash values will be the address of accessing the data. Now, since the hash values will be randomly distributed, I have to insert and read data from the hash tables randomly. What is the best way to implement such a design? I cant use the arrays in RAM since it will cause overflow. Will I be benefited by using the mmap? Or any other design scheme.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What does "The hash values will be addresses of accessing the data" mean? The key is a memory address of something you control? Then why don't you store the data next to that address, implicitly? This would significantly reduce the size (no keys, no empty slots if open addressing, no links if chaining), perhaps fitting it into RAM.

Comment: Umm, Yeah. I am doing that only. I think there was a misCommunication. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) supports on-disk hash tables.

Comment: Wow, dint know such a tool exists. Thanks a lot. :) I will look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying that the hash tables can't fit into `RAM`, I think of storing these `hash tables` on the `hard disk` in the form of files, where each value can be stored in a different line or in a `delimiter` seperated fashion.

Whenever you want to update a value in the file, I would suggest you that instead of reading the whole file and updating a value which is rather slow, you can store some information about the exact location of each value at the beginning of the file, and just `seek` to that position and update it. Regarding `mmap`, you can still prefer it, because it performs `demand paging` in bringing a file into the memory. But I guess this can't be faster than one-time `seek and write` instead of every time bringing part of the file when a `page-fault` occurs.

Comment: Yeah. mmap will be an extra overhead. I am currently looking at BDB as pointed out by @larsmans